# Why I can't rebuild zendesk_ios_sdk?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, armv7, zendesk

I updated XCode to the latest version (4.5). When I tried to compile my project, the console gave me this error:

> ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s
>   slice:
>   /Users/myuser/Documents/MyProjectDirectory/libZendeskDropbox.a
>   for architecture armv7s

So I downloaded [zendesk_ios_sdk source from githu](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_ios_sdk)b and followed the instructions on the readme file, at the 3rd step I got this error:

> can't open input file:
>   /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZendeskDropboxIOS-cnginhrdnonxxrantdlwohdmmdot/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/../Release-iphonesimulator/libZendeskiPhoneSimulator.a
>   (No such file or directory)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded the source from Github and it seems that the script for combining the libraries expects a Release build but the project is set up to do a Debug build for the ZendeskiPhone and ZendeskiPhoneSimulator schemes

Edit Schemes for the ZendeskiPhone and ZendeskiPhoneSimulator schemes so the build configuration is Release and then follow the instructions again (screenshots below)

[image: Edit Scheme]

[image: Select Project]

[image: Change to Release]